# What control should be appropiate to show a Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, datatemplateselector, datatemplate

I can't find a better title for this.

I have many canvas drawings and depending of a parameter in my program, should display the respective canvas

EX:

```
- PARAMETER: 1  OUTPUT: CANVAS1
- PARAMETER: 2  OUTPUT: CANVAS2
```

I was reading in internet that one way would be... Each one of these canvas should be inside of a `DataTemplate`, and use a `DataTemplateSelector` to choose the respective `DataTemplate`.

I guess the control which I can use to show that is a `ContentControl` , but my question is, in Content property should I bind the `PARAMATER`, right?